# Jersey + Eclipse + Jetty : Serialization of polymorphic types results to a java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EXTERNAL_PROPERTY exception on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: eclipse, jetty, jersey, polymorphism

I experience a very strange problem and I don't have found any help to resolve it. I'm developing an app using Jersey to provides RESTfull services that are accessed by a GWT website. Services produce Json contents that are deserialized by RestyGWT. Everything works fine until I wanted to serialize polymorphic types. I also use Shiro to protect returned values to unauthorized users.

The serialization process run well on Mac OS X Lion using Eclipse Indigo and included Jetty as webserver. It also work well by using Tomcat 6. When I'm on Linux (an Ubuntu 12.04 distro), the app run well by using Tomcat 6 but when I use Ecplise's included Jetty as webserver, the exception below is always thrown.

I tried to update each lib to the latest stable version as I read in some posts. Does anyone has experienced this problem ?

Thank you in advence.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EXTERNAL_PROPERTY
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector._findTypeResolver(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:781)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.findTypeResolver(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:199)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector$Pair.findTypeResolver(AnnotationIntrospector.java:1032)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.createTypeSerializer(BasicSerializerFactory.java:200)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.buildContainerSerializer(BasicSerializerFactory.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:268)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:782)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:735)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:344)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:420)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:256)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1613)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.writeTo(JacksonJsonProvider.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1451)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1097)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:380)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1088)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:829)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the same exception was caused by having restygwt library on the Classpath.

Comment: You are right, I've tested with the version 1.3 and this exception did not occur. I don't know if the problem was the binding between Jackson and RestGWT but it seems to. Thanks for the response !!

Comment: You are welcome! My solution so far has been to remove restygwt from the project classpatth and add it only to the GWT run configuration. But this way I've the classes that uses restygwt marked as Error which is pretty ugly.
Please let me know if you find a better way to go around this issue. For example a possible solution could be merge restygwt with its dependencies in one jar but I haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 1):

RestGwt includes the Jackson Annotation Classes in it's own source tree. This then leds to version conflicts between the Jackson library and RestyGwt beginning with the Jackson 1.9, where in the JsonTypeInfo Class new Enummeration Value for the As Enum was introduced (EXTERNAL_PROPERTY), which is resolved at Runtime and thus leds to the above Exception. 
My solution was to back to the 1.7.1 Version of Jackson. Note aside: From my point of view the redundant inclusion of the source code, is not the way to resolve dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of your `Jackson` is 1.9 or bigger, because this enum was added in 1.9.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I was already using the version 1.9.7. I read on a forum to check the version of Jackson libs but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue recently with a GWT 2.4 application, using Jackson 1.9.7 and RestyGWT 1.3.

We're using one of [Thomas Broyer's archetypes](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes) which produces three different Maven projects for the GWT app. We have RestyGWT included as a dependency in client and shared projects. Because the server project has a dependency on the shared one, we had a dependency (received transitively) on RestyGWT on the server project. So, in order to make it work I excluded the RestyGWT dependency when setting the shared project dependency on server project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.pst</groupId>
    <artifactId>accounts-ui-shared</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
           <groupId>org.fusesource.restygwt</groupId>
           <artifactId>restygwt</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is to exclude the old Jackson lib from your RestyGWT dependency, while ensuring the most recent one will supercede it :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.fusesource.restygwt</groupId>
   <artifactId>restygwt</artifactId>
   <version>1.3</version>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.9</version>
</dependency>
```